# How to make a list using strings from another list?

Tags: python, list

So, in this code, I'm trying to make `list_1` a list of 8 strings from `alp_list` where no strings are the same, and to delete the items in `list_1` from `alp_list` for more codes. I'm not sure what's the best way to do this.

```
import random

alp_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
a = 0
list_1 = []
while a < 9:
    random_alp = random.choices(alp_list)
    list_1.append(random_alp)
    alp_list.remove(random_alp)
    a += 1
print (list_1)
```

Comment: Just a small point, if you choose to stay with this kind of loop: instead of using a counter (which most Pythonistas try to avoid at all costs), you can say something like `while len(list_1) < 9`.

Comment: Just as another option to consider, what you're doing is very similar to shuffling and dealing from a deck of cards.  You could do `random.shuffle(alp_list)`, and then just pull items from the top using `.pop(0)` or by slicing (`alp_list[:9]`).

Answer (score 3):

You may use a preexisting function:

```
list_1 = random.sample(alp_list, 8)
```

To delete the items from the original list, you may go with:

```
for item in list_1:
    alp_list.remove(item)
```

Comment: It's convenient for sure, but they also want to remove from the original list.